# Getting the sum of values in a field

Tags: bash, date, datetime, sh

I have a text file which contains this kind of entries:

```
SERVER02 |smsgateway0004 |0 |20160521 00:01:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0001 |0 |20160521 00:01:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway1003 |0 |20160521 00:01:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway0002 |0 |20160521 00:02:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0002 |0 |20160521 00:02:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway1002 |0 |20160521 00:02:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway1002 |0 |20160521 00:03:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0004 |0 |20160521 00:03:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0002 |0 |20160521 00:03:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway0001 |0 |20160521 00:04:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0005 |0 |20160521 00:04:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0001 |0 |20160521 00:04:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway0003 |0 |20160521 00:05:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0003 |0 |20160521 00:05:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0005 |0 |20160521 00:05:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway0005 |0 |20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER06 |smsgateway0005 |0 |20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway1001 |0 |20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway1001 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER06 |smsgateway0003 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0003 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER06 |smsgateway0004 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0004 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
```

The first field is the server name, the second is the instance, the third one is the count, the fourth one is the date and the last one is the timestamp.

What I wanted to do is get the summation of the third column for each minute of the timestamp. (e.g. the sum of 00:02:00.0 from all the server is 4119).

Basically, I want to find the sum of all the count that fell under a specific timestamp.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBaZn.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F '[ |]+' '{arr[$5]+=$3} END{for(key in arr) print key, arr[key]}' data 
00:07:00.0 0
00:06:00.0 0
00:05:00.0 0
00:04:00.0 0
00:03:00.0 0
00:02:00.0 0
00:01:00.0 0
```

Since all of your values are 0, I've put some dummy data:

```
$ cat data 
SERVER02 |smsgateway0004 |2 |20160521 00:01:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0001 |0 |20160521 00:01:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway1003 |5 |20160521 00:01:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway0002 |0 |20160521 00:02:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0002 |0 |20160521 00:02:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway1002 |0 |20160521 00:02:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway1002 |0 |20160521 00:03:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0004 |0 |20160521 00:03:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0002 |0 |20160521 00:03:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway0001 |0 |20160521 00:04:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0005 |0 |20160521 00:04:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0001 |0 |20160521 00:04:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway0003 |6 |20160521 00:05:00.0
SERVER05 |smsgateway0003 |5 |20160521 00:05:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0005 |0 |20160521 00:05:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway0005 |0 |20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER06 |smsgateway0005 |0 |20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway1001 |0 |20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway1001 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER06 |smsgateway0003 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0003 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER06 |smsgateway0004 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway0004 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
$ awk -F '[ |]+' '{arr[$5]+=$3} END{for(key in arr) print key, arr[key]}' data 
00:07:00.0 0
00:06:00.0 0
00:05:00.0 11
00:04:00.0 0
00:03:00.0 0
00:02:00.0 0
00:01:00.0 7
```

Comment: You don't have to escape the pipe if it is inside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that I understand what you want, but here we go:

```
awk '$5 ~ /00:07:00/ {sum += substr($3, 2)} END{print sum}' input_file
```

This code will match all lines that have `00:07:00` in the fifth field. Then take your third field and add them together.

In your example output everything will give 0, but with input as:

```
SERVER02 |smsgateway0005 |10|20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER06 |smsgateway0005 |22|20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER03 |smsgateway1001 |13|20160521 00:06:00.0
SERVER02 |smsgateway1001 |0 |20160521 00:07:00.0
SERVER06 |smsgateway0003 |11|20160521 00:07:00.0
```

The output would be 11 for `00:07:00` and 45 for `00:06:00`